# Angular Mat-Slider Use With NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am developing an Angular 10 app and within one of my templates I have a list of Angular Material `mat-expansion-panel` (Accordion) which are bound to an array of Task Groups which I obtain using an NGRX Selector.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let taskGroup of taskGroups; let i = index"
  [expanded]="i == openPanelIndex"
  (click)="onClickTaskGroup($event, taskGroup)"
  (mouseover)="onMouseoverExpansionPanel(i)"
  style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
...
```

Within each Expansion Panel's content (when opened) is a further list of Tasks for the opened Task Group, also provided using an NGRX Selector.

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let task of tasksForSelectedTaskGroup; let i = index"
  (click)="onClickTask(task)"
  style="width: 100%;">
...
```

Each Task item in the Task list includes a `mat-slider` to set an angle from 0 to 360.

```
...
<mat-slider color="accent"
  min="0" max="360"
  step="5" tick="1"
  thumbLabel
  [disabled]="angleDisabled"
  [value]="task.deviceAngle"
  (input)="onAngleSliderInputChange($event, task)"
  style="padding-left: 0; width: 100%"></mat-slider>
```

I am trying to slide the Slider and using the Slider's `input` event dispatch an Action to update the Tasks in the NGRX Store which other components displayed on the screen subscribe to. The other components, on receiving an updated array of Tasks, will then rotate to reflect the new angle.

What I am experiencing however is as follows: I slide the Slider enough to change the `input` value, the Store is updated and this change is detected by my Selectors and this appears to cause the Accordion and/or the Task list to refresh and the Slider jump either to the very right or it to de-select and prevent me sliding it. I tried removing the `[value]="task.deviceAngle"` binding but this didn't help. I don't want to use the `change` event because the user needs a visual feedback as they slide the Slider.

I feel I somehow need to disconnect the Accordion or Task list from updating while I am sliding the Slider and then, using the `change` event perhaps update everything when I have finished.

Any suggestions or advise very welcome.

Comment: Can you provide a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smyels) with an example of your problem?

Comment: What I'd suggest with what you've provided, set a `debounceTime` on your `onAngleSliderInputChange` event so that you only update it when the slider has stopped sliding, and also add `trackBy` functions to your `ngFor`'s.

Comment: `trackBy` is a great suggestion. I have used it elsewhere in my app and it may be helpful. I have been looking at using `detach` and `reattach` to control change detection. I'll perform some tests and get back.